# Dynamic page load can't load Java with page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have tried to load html element and it works most ways but the problem is trying to load and run the included script tag in the page. Any ideas or tutorials that would help would be great.

jquery Script:

var default_content="";

$(document).ready(function(){

```
checkURL();
$('ul li a').click(function (e){

        checkURL(this.hash);

});

//filling in the default content
default_content = $('#MainContent').html();


setInterval("checkURL()",250);
```

});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

```
if(hash != lasturl)
{
    lasturl=hash;



    if(hash=="")
    $('#MainContent').html(default_content);

    else
    loadPage(hash);
}
```

}

function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#page','');

```
$('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_page.php",
    data: 'page='+url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {
            $('#MainContent').html(msg);
            $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
    }

});
```

}

This routs by way of a small PHP file that shows where the pages live.
The scripts are brought in to the HTML this way but will not execute. On my page i have a toggle script that moves some elements and it will not execute even with an "on click". 
my curent thinking is to use the $.getScripts() but everything must be external for that to work and even then it may not exicute.

Comment: Provide source code that demonstrates the problem, as well as examples of what you've already done to try and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code... have you tried putting your script tag at the bottom of your document (therefore letting everything load)?

edit: Sorry I would have commented but I don't have enough reputation yet. Will avoid answers like this in the future

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  Questions regarding the original question should be posted in the comments to the question -- not as answers.

Comment: this is one way of loading. It pulls the in-page java in but won't execute it.   --->